# DolphinDB: Error when using dynamic functions in SQL statements

Tags: sql, dynamic-programming, dolphindb

The following is my script:

```
sym = `C`MS`MS`MS`IBM`IBM`C`C`C$SYMBOL
price= 49.6 29.46 29.52 30.02 174.97 175.23 50.76 50.32 51.29
qty = 2200 1900 2100 3200 6800 5400 1300 2500 8800
timestamp = [09:34:07,09:36:42,09:36:51,09:36:59,09:32:47,09:35:26,09:34:16,09:34:26,09:38:12]
t1 = table(timestamp, sym, qty, price)

//select *, cumsum(qty) from t1 context by sym
//select *, cumsum2(qty) from t1 context by sym

def demo(t, dynamicFunc) {
        return select select *, dynamicFunc(qty) from t context by sym
}

demo(t1, cumsum)
```

The statement `return select *, dynamicFunc(qty) as dynamicFunc_qty from t context by sym` raises an error: `Not allowed to use dynamic function in sql statement`.

The “dynamic function“, `dynamicFunc`, is passed as a parameter, which cannot be executed in SQL statements. How to solve this error in DolphinDB?

Answer (score 0):

Using dynamic functions in SQL statements is supported by DolphinDB server 3.00, but not by server 2.00. You can use the `call` function to solve this issue as follows:

```
def demo(t, dynamicFunc) {
        return select *, call(dynamicFunc, qty) from t11 context by sym
}
```